# Texmaker: Move "External Viewer" button in the embedded viewer

Tags: texmaker

I really like using Texmaker in mac OS but the way I have my work area set up I cannot easily access the button to open the external viewer from the embedded viewer window (I like it squished up to the side). In order to click the button, I have to press the >> button to bring up the option. Is there any way I can change the ordering of the embedded viewer buttons or hide some of them?

I like using the embedded viewer as my default, so I don't want to change anything about my setup, other than where that external viewer button is.

[image]

Comment: Check out Texstudio, it is very similar to Texmaker but you can customize the buttons in the menu bar

Answer (score 5):

Well for your screenshot it seems to be the last version with QT5 that has not the menu above and that's disgusting, at least for me. But if I am wrong, you should see above, in the finder bar I think, the menu and if you click above `Options` choose the first option: `Configure Texmaker` it opens a new window.

[image: Window configuration from TeXmaker]

Below in the right side of the screen is the section `Pdf viewer` where you can see the options, please check the `Embed` one. Close the window and perhaps you'll need to restart the program.

As you can see I'm using `gnu/linux` (Ubuntu actually) but it should fix it.

Comment: thx alot man!..

Comment: Then you can choose the best answer clicking over the check symbol.